# Odoo how to display many2one inside of order form

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I starting to learn odoo framework.

I am trying to display carrier_id  which lives inside of sale.order model  diplay inside of the "sale.view_order_form"

**Error I get  "carrier_id doesnt exist"**

Here its my code, I hope someone can help me to understand.

PYTHON

```
from odoo import fields, models

    class carrierId(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'delivery.carrier'
    
        #add incoming carrier information
        carrier_id = fields.Many2one('delivery.carrier', 'Carrier',)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_form_add_carrier">   
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />      
        <field name="arch" type="xml">      
                <field name="pricelist_id" position="after">
                    <field name="carrier_id"/>
                </field>    
        </field>    
    </record>   
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML adds the `carrier_id` field to the `sale.order`model.

But the model change is adding the `carrier_id` field to the `delivery_carrier` model, not `sale.order`.

You probably want o add the fields to the `sale.order`model instead.

By the way, the module `delivery` already does that, so you should consider installing it instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it work by changing the _inherit:   to sale.order.   BUT.  what do you mean I can install the module DELIVERY?    I just found the website_sale_delivery but I dont think its that one right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant :

```
_inherit = 'sale.order'
```

instead of :

```
_inherit = 'delivery.carrier'
```